# Try to writing and open PDF in Python without success

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pypdf

This my code in Python:

```
import pydf

pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>Empresa Jucla</h1>')

with open('test_doc.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pdf)
```

which is generating this error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\juppe\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/juppe/modulos_externos.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/juppe/modulos_externos.py", line 32, in <module>
    pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>Empresa Jucla</h1>')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\juppe\lib\site-packages\pydf\wkhtmltopdf.py", line 145, in generate_pdf
    p = _execute_wk(*cmd_args, input=html.encode())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\juppe\lib\site-packages\pydf\wkhtmltopdf.py", line 30, in _execute_wk
    return subprocess.run(wk_args, input=input, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I'm working on Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `with open('test_doc.pdf', 'wb') as f: f.write(pdf)`
In your code, f should be the parameter. According to the documentation:

```
with open('test_doc.pdf', "wb") as f:
            pdf.write(f)
```

Notice how this differs from writing to a csv for example, where your syntax would be correct.

Comment: It does not worked... with the code ( pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>Empresa Jucla</h1>')

with open('test_doc.pdf', "wb") as f:
    pdf.write(f) )

Comment: C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\juppe\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/juppe/modulos_externos.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/juppe/modulos_externos.py", line 32, in <module>
    pdf = pydf.generate_pdf('<h1>Empresa Jucla</h1>')
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Envs\juppe\lib\site-packages\pydf\wkhtmltopdf.py", line 145, in generate_pdf
    p = _execute_wk(*cmd_args, input=html.encode())  ......THE SAME ERROR...

Comment: Also, try using pypdf2

Answer (score 0):

Ran across this issue just now and spent most of my day running around for a solution when it was quite simple in fact...

So, when you access [pypi.org's python-pdf page](https://pypi.org/project/python-pdf/) you immediately get the following information from the package developer:

"If you’re on another OS or architecture your mileage may vary, it is likely that you’ll need to supply your own `wkhtmltopdf` binary and point **pydf** towards it by setting the `WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH` environment variable."

So basically, python-pdf is prepared for Linux.

What you'll need to do is: after installing python-pdf package, you just need to access its directory, go to bin and delete the file there (mine was here: `C:\Users\Diogo Almeida\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydf\bin`).

After you've deleted that file, just go to the [wkhtmltopdf download page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) and download the most suitable file for your OS.

Install the exe wherever you want, and once it is complete, you will only need to access the directory that the installer created and cut the file in bin folder named "wkhtmltopdf" (which is also an exe) and paste it back on `C:\Users\Diogo Almeida\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydf\bin`.

Finally go to your py file and run the code again.